# Replacing cyrillic symbol in attribute table using python?

Tags: arcpy, internationalization

I've tried searching for an answer and I've already seen some similar themes here, but I still haven't been successful in replacing Cyrillic symbols in an attribute table, which is why I'm asking for help. The aim is to find a Cyrillic symbol (if it is in a field) and then change it, otherwise leave other non-Cyrillic characters as they were.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that all of ArcGIS' Python stuff dealing with strings starting in 9.3 uses Unicode objects, which will make your life quite a bit easier because encoding becomes less of a big deal in the data. You'll still need to think about it in your scripts, but if you use UTF-8 in any Python source you write outside of dialogs in Arc*.exe ArcGIS will handle it fine. When looking out into scripts on disk, ArcGIS assumes they're in UTF-8.

Now, opening up charmap we find the Cyrillic characters nestled comfortably in between Coptic and Armenian. The first character is capital Io (Ё), which charmap tells us is U+0401. In Python, this can be represented in a unicode literal as `u'\u0401'`. The last character is small Yeru with diaresis (ӹ), U+04F9 (`u'\u04f9'`). So we want to filter out all the characters 0x0401-0x04f9.

This is one of the very few places where a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#module-re) really *is* the right tool for the job. To represent the range, we use the expression `[\u0401-\u04f9]`. From there, we can use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace it with nothing. This is how we'd do that:

```
 my_new_attribute_string = re.sub(u'[\u0401-\u04f9]', '', my_old_attribute_string)
```

And this should do it.

You can also use [`re.compile`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.compile) if you're going to reuse the same expression over and over to save some time. For example, a script that replaces all cyrillic in a specific column in a table:

```
import re

import arcpy

cyrillic_substitution = re.compile(u'[\u0401-\u04f9]')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(my_feature_class, column_with_cyrillic) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        row[0] = cyrillic_substitution.sub("", row[0])
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a [good answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14173535/327026) that translates Cyrillic to Latin. Here is the logic:

```
symbols = (u"абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхъыьэАБВГДЕЁЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЪЫЬЭ",
           u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'eABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'E")

tr = {ord(a): ord(b) for a, b in zip(*symbols)}

def cyrillic2latin(input):
    return input.translate(tr)
```

E.g. `cyrillic2latin(u'Москва')` returns `u'Moskva'`.

Comment: Letters "ЦЧШЩЮЯ" are missing.